# Scrape data from a Web App designed using AngularJS

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to scrape data from a WebApp using JSoup. But the problem is, the Web application doesn't store the entity's name, It just uses a variable to display content. For example: Expedia uses the 'hotelName' variable to display the hotel's actual name. So, how do I scrape this data using JSoup?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342174/scrape-an-angularjs-website-with-java