# jsoup output in angularjs web

Tags: java, angularjs, web, jsoup

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.example.com/p/laptop-aksesoris").get();
Element element = doc.select("div.product-card a").first();
Elements elements = element.getElementsByAttribute("href");
for (Element e:elements) {
 System.out.println("url: " + e.attr("href"));
 System.out.println("text: " + e.text());
}
```

output:

> url: {{model.url}}
>
> text: {{model.name}} {{model.price}} {{e.title}} Grosir {{wp.quantity_min}} - {{wp.quantity_max}} ≥ {{wp.quantity_min}} {{wp.price}} PO

this web using angularjs(version 1) for froent-end.
when i try web without angularjs, it's work well.

Questions:

what the happen?
how can i fix that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Jsoup has does not provide JavaScript support. Combination with HtmlUnit might work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrape an angularjs website with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342174/scrape-an-angularjs-website-with-java)

Comment: @FredericKlein thanks. you right.

but when i using HtmlUnit, the output same.
still like that.

have you any ide, please.

Comment: Try it with PhantomJS (trigger execution from java, write output into a file, parse file with java): http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK jsoup just parses HTML and DOM elements. It does not execute javascript and hence cannot parse any AngularJS dynamic elements.