# How to get a number from a website for an an android app use

Tags: java, android, selenium, jsoup

I have a question regarding **scraping** data form a website.

There is this exchange rate website that I want to use to get the exchange amount after an exchange from USD to EURO :

> https://www.paysera.com/v2/en-DZ/fees/currency-conversion-calculator#/?locale=lt&clientType=natural&from_currency=USD&from_amount=100&to_currency=EUR

I found out that if you add any number after **from_amount=** and before the **&to_currency=EUR** (XXX), it will calculate the exchange rate of that exact amount; The exchange rate isn’t constant, so it depends on the amount.

What I want to do is make the user input the amount (inpDollar) then add it between **from_amount=** and **&to_currency=EUR**; Then extract the amount as a number.

The exact location of the amount i want is shown in this screenshot

[https://i.imgur.com/79xGeG9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqxf7.png)

I’ve read some threads about Jsoup and Selenium, i have already added them to my dependencies, but I don’t have the necessary knowledge to write that kind of code.

I want to use this inside an android app (android studio) to automate some calculations.

Thank for your help.

Comment: The site you're trying to scrape seems to be an Angular application. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751981/jsoup-output-in-angularjs-web) seems related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Please take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions about it.

In the code below, the user is asked for dollarvalue [Please enter dollar values in your editor and press enter]. The value is used in the URL and when the page opens with data, the required value is retrieved.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the Dollar Value :- ");
String dollarValue = input.nextLine();


driver.get(String.format("https://www.paysera.com/v2/en-DZ/fees/currency-conversion-calculator#/?locale=lt&client" +
    "Type=natural&from_currency=USD&from_amount=%s&to_currency=EUR", dollarValue));

String calculatedValue = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//span[@class=\"commercial-rate\"]/span"))).getText();
System.out.println("CalculatedValue is " + calculatedValue);
```

for launching a browser in the background you can use the below code -

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless", "--silent");
```

Note - All the classes I mentioned above must be imported. If I forgot any, import them as well.

Comment: Thank you, this have worked for me on my IDEA, i just added driver path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/userPC/chromedriver.exe"); how can i do  this on android studio inside an app ?